# Ruby Version does not match

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I used brew to update ruby and it shows that 3.0.1 is installed. However, when I use ruby -v the version shows to me is 2.3.7. Why does it happen and how can I get around it?

```
brew upgrade ruby
Warning: ruby 3.0.1 already installed
(base) d-172-25-143-111:~ cd5$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

Comment: It's better to use a ruby version manager instead of homebrew if you need a non-system ruby. I use chruby, but there are others, like rbenv and RVM.

Comment: did you installed rvm ? if yes check rvm list and then rvm use 3.0.1

Comment: "Why does it happen" - it's in the `$PATH`, I'd wager. Not sure where brew installed ruby on your machine, but that dir is either missing from PATH or comes after `/usr/bin` (where the system ruby lives)

Comment: @Bodh1004 yes I used rvm. Even when I use RVM it shows different version  ```(base) d-172-25-143-111:~ cd5$ rvm list
   ruby-3.0.0 [ x86_64 ]```

Comment: @EPUVA RVM will not pick up rubies from homebrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with all shell commands, you should check how your shell is actually looking up the command:

```
type -a ruby
```

For me that shows

```
ruby is /Users/max/.rbenv/shims/ruby
ruby is /usr/bin/ruby
```

Which indicates that I have two different Rubies installed, the one from rbenv taking precedence. This is almost certainly the case for you as well: you have multiple `ruby` executables, and the one from Homebrew is either not in that list (meaning it isn't somewhere in your `PATH`) or it is lower in the list than something else.